How to move an Ubuntu LAMP server VM from a Xen orchestra host to a hyper-V host
I have no credentials to access the Ubuntu LAMP server except via cPanel which has terminal access and wish to move this Ubuntu LAMP VM from a Xen Orchestra Host to a Hyper-V host.
I was thinking of using using rsync but have never used it, any suggestions would be much appreciated.
